# Why is it more recommended to use 'val' instead of 'var'?

Tags: kotlin, variables, backend

Recently, I was taking a Kotlin course, and the instructor mentioned that the recommendation is, whenever possible, to use 'val' instead of 'var'. What would be the reason behind this recommendation?

Examplo:

```
var name: String = "Jannayna"

or

val name: String = "Jannayna"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `val` (without custom `get()`), you know the value won’t change, which makes all your code that uses that property or variable easier to reason about because there are less “moving parts” to keep under consideration.

In Kotlin, a variable or property is either a `val` or a `var` instead of like some other languages where a variable is by default mutable and can be restricted with a keyword like `final` or `const`. Therefore, when you see `var` instead of `val`, you know the writer of that code intentionally made it mutable and weren’t just being lazy by omitting a keyword. So using `var` communicates that the variable or property is not just mutable, but *expected* to be mutated at some point.

Comment: Mmm.  For one example, using `val` for properties can prevent some race conditions and other concurrency-related bugs (concurrency is notoriously subtle and hard to get right) — and may let the compiler/runtime make some optimisations, as it knows another thread can't change the value.